# The (0,0) point gets messed up with a status bar on the iPhone

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When I launch my iOS app, it launches in portrait mode. I initially turn the phone to landscape mode, and successfully resize my UIViews to fit the new screen. Then, I push a new UIViewController, which sizes components based on the current orientation in the viewDidLoad method. If it is landscape mode, it draws a UINavigationBar starting at (0,0) with length equal to the height of the iPhone, and height equal to 50.

Well, the UINavigationBar gets offset (the (0,0) point of it is off the screen) by an amount exactly equal to the height of the status bar. Why does the (0,0) point get messed up, and how do I fix this?

**Let me just say that without the status bar (if I add the option to initially hide it), these problems do not exist.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You UIViewController is getting offset and the your coordiinates within the view are still at 0, 0.

Try re-setting the position of the ViewController.

```
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Comment: Not even `viewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

Comment: Or try setting `[viewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];`

Comment: Are you adding the view controller to the main screen or are you adding it to another view?

Comment: I'm adding it to the main screen using  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];

Comment: Aha! it being a modal view was a very important factor. Read this: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/12/29/snippet-full-screen-presentmodalviewcontroller/

Comment: wait a sec so what do I do? lol. set clipsToBound=NO? that article is describing a little bit of a different problem. I want my status bar to stay in the app.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a modal? Can you simply place this view on top of the other or replace it?

Comment: to be honest, I don't even know what a modal is...I want to be able to dismiss the view though...

Comment: weirdd!!! when I changed animated from NO to YES, it worked (when presenting the modal view controller). what the heck is going on...?

Comment: Layering is probably different when it's animated. Does it work without my contributions?

Comment: wait. false alarm. still doesn't work fully. works only sometimes

Comment: sometimes when dismissing a controller, it goes back to being glitched, but only in certain orientations. ugh. the status bar is so annoying.